# Unresolved External Symbol when initializing pointer to a template

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers, stack

Please have a look at the following code

**Weapon.h**

**

```
#pragma once
#include "GameObject.h"
#include "Stack.h"
#include "Round.h"
class Weapon :
    public GameObject
{
public:
    Weapon(int);
    ~Weapon(void);
    Stack <Round> *stack1(int rounds) ;
    Weapon *next;
    void display();
};
```

**

**Weapon.cpp**

```
#include "Weapon.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Weapon::Weapon(int size)
{
    stack1(size);
}


Weapon::~Weapon(void)
{
}

void Weapon::display()
{
    cout << "Weapon Id: " << id << endl;
}
```

Please note that the above is just 2 files of a project code. However I am getting the following error when I run it

```
1>------ Build started: Project: stacksCheck, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Weapon.cpp
1>Weapon.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class Stack<class Round> * __thiscall Weapon::stack1(int)" (?stack1@Weapon@@QAEPAV?$Stack@VRound@@@@H@Z)
1>C:\Users\yohan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CourseWork2\Debug\CourseWork2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am 100% sure this error comes from here

```
stack1(size);
```

Whenever I remove this, the code works fine!!

`stack1` is an object to a Stack class, where the constructor of the stack class accepts an integer parameter. The `Stack` class is a template, located in a header file

How can I get rid  of this error?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `stack1` is supposed to be a data member of `Weapon` (and not a function), you should declare this as:

```
class Weapon :
    public GameObject
{
public:
    Weapon(int);
    ~Weapon(void);

    Stack <Round>   stack1;
    Weapon *next;

    void display();
};
```

and then initialize it in the `Weapon` constructor

```
Weapon::Weapon(int size) : stack1(size)
{ }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you declare a function for which you provide no definition:

```
class Weapon : public GameObject
{
public:
    ...
    Stack <Round> *stack1(int rounds) ; // <=== DECLARATION IS HERE,
                                        //      DEFINITION IS NOWHERE
    ...
};
```

Obviously, the linker complains that it can't find the definition of `Weapon::stack1()`.

> Whenever I remove this, the code works fine!!

No wonder, you're no more invoking a declared, yet undefined function. You should add a definition for `Weapon::stack1()` to your implementation file:

**Weapon.cpp**

```
...

Stack<Round>* stack1(int round)
{
    ...
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> `stack1` is an object to a `Stack` class, where the constructor of the stack class accepts an integer parameter. The `Stack` class is a template, located in a header file

I overlooked this part when I first answered the question.

So even though you are declaring a *function*, it seems your intention is to declare a *pointer* to an object of type `Stack<Round>`. In that case, forget about defining a `stack1()` function, as I suggested in the original answer. Just use the correct syntax for declaring a pointer member variable:

**Weapon.h**

```
class Weapon : public GameObject
{
public:
    ...
    Stack<Round>* stack1; // IF YOU WANT TO DECLARE A MEMBER POINTER,
                          // THIS IS THE CORRECT SYNTAX.
    ...
};
```

Then, in the constructor of your `Weapon` class, you can construct the `Stack<Round>` object and assign the pointer:

**Weapon.cpp**

```
Weapon::Weapon(int size)
{
    stack1 = new Stack<Round>(size);
}
```

Also, do not forget to `delete stack1` in `Weapon`'s destructor:

```
Weapon::~Weapon(int size)
{
    if (stack1)
    {
        delete stack1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in Weapon constructor:

```
stack1=new Stack <Round>(size);
```

Also update Weapon.h:

```
 Stack <Round> *stack1;
```